# Filtering Rows Based On Number of Columns with AWK

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have lines of data that contain 
single column and two columns. What I want to do is to 
extract lines that contain only 2 columns.

```
0333 foo
 bar
23243 qux
```

yielding only:

```
0333 foo
23243 qux
```

Note that they are tab separated, even for lines with only one column
you have tab at the beginning.

What's the way to do it?

I tried this but fail:

```
awk '$1!="";{print $1 "\t" $2}' myfile.txt

enter code here
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to use the `NF` (number of fields) variable to control the actions, such as in the following transcript:

```
$ echo '0333 foo
>  bar
> 23243 qux' | awk 'NF==2{print}{}'
0333 foo
23243 qux
```

This will print the line if the number of fields is two, otherwise it will do nothing. The reason I have the (seemingly) strange construct `NF==2{print}{}` is because some implementations of `awk` will print by default if no rules are matched for a line. The empty command `{}` guarantees that this will not happen.

If you're lucky enough to have one of those that doesn't do this, you can get away with:

```
awk 'NF==2'
```

but the first solution above will work in *both* cases.

Comment: Why not `awk 'NF==2{print}{}{}{}{}{}{}'` ??  NF==2 suffices.

Comment: @Mark, some implementations of `awk` will print by default if you don't specify a default action. My code works on those ones as well. You bods are spoilt with your GNU awk, some of us have to write portable code :-) I'll clarify.

Comment: @ pax, An awk implementation which behaves the way you describe would be pretty broken.  As far as I know, awk dates to v7, and the manual there pretty clearly describes its behavior: "for example, the program length > 72 prints all input lines whose length exceeds 72 characters."

Answer (score 9):

```
awk 'NF==2' file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '(NF==2){print}' test.txt
```